# if elif is giving the wrong result

Tags: python, calculator

It's only giving me the result of the first operation which is multiplied even if my input was the addition.

```
print('Calculator')
operation = input('Choose:\n Mltiply(*)\n Divise\(/)\n Add(+)\n Subbstract(-)\n ')
if operation == 'mutiply' or 'Multiply' or 'MULTIPLY' or '*':
    num1 = input('Write Your number :')
    num2 = input('Write your next number :')
    result = float(num1) * float(num2)
    print(result )
elif operation == 'DIVISE' or 'divise' or 'Divise' or '/':
    num1 = input('Write Your number :')
    num2 = input('Write your next number :')
    result = float(num1) / float(num2)
    print(result )
elif operation == 'Add' or 'add' or 'ADD' or '+':
    num1 = input('Write Your number :')
    num2 = input('Write your next number :')
    result = float(num1) + float(num2)
    print(result )
elif operation == 'Subbstract' or 'subbstract' or 'SUBBSTRACT' or '-':
    num1 = input('Write Your number :')
    num2 = input('Write your next number :')
    result = float(num1) - float(num2)
    print(result )
else:
    print('SYNTAX ERROR')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the in operator

```
elif operation in {'DIVISE', 'divise', 'Divise', '/'}:
```

for every if/else block.

EDIT:
You can find a good explanation here:
[Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True? How can I compare "a" to all of those?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al)

Answer (score 1):

Use `in`

```
print('Calculator')
operation = input('Choose:\n Mltiply(*)\n Divise\(/)\n Add(+)\n Subbstract(-)\n ')
if operation.lower() in ['mutiply', '*']:
    num1 = input('Write Your number :')
    num2 = input('Write your next number :')
    result = float(num1) * float(num2)
    print(result )
elif operation.lower() in ['mutiply', '*']:
    num1 = input('Write Your number :')
    num2 = input('Write your next number :')
    result = float(num1) / float(num2)
    print(result )
..... replicate the above code for other operations ....
```

**Why is your code always meet the fist condition?**

`operation == 'mutiply' or 'Multiply' or 'MULTIPLY' or '*'` this always gives you `True`,

```
if 'Multiply':
     # Always return true
```

Comment: Can I know what is the functionof operation.lower() ?

Comment: `"ABCdef".lower()` -> `"abcdef"`.

Comment: @TNZ Any reason you for the answer acceptance?